# AppBarLayout with tabs and ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem with `TabLayout`and `AppBarLayout`, because I want my tabs to be at the bottom and right now they are at the top, they hide with the image as I scroll up. And there's the second problem - `AppBarLayout` with image doesn't hide as I scroll the text, it only hides/shows as I try to `scroll` image at the top

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@raw/test"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_scrollview">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ip"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what view is the text wrapped in to handle scroll?

Comment: `ScrollView`, i'll make an edit to include that

Comment: Change it to a NestedScrollView along with my updated solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll view doesn't support Appbar behaviors, change it to NestedScrollView and use the following layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
  android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout
```

Comment: I don‘t think it would be necessary to wrap it in NestedScrollView

Comment: That is in case, the textview is not wrapped in a scrollview and that part of the code is not pasted.

Comment: when i do this, it throws "has stopped" error with this message android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: Yeah, am sorry. The AppBarLayout can handle scrolls only when the child view heirarchy of the view with the ScrollingViewBehavior (viewpager in your case) consists a scrollable view. Does the view heirarchy contain a scrolling member ?

Comment: Yeah, that works, i mean, changing `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`. Your solution witch catching everything in `LinearLayout` also works just as  jle's solution. Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2):

Try to add gravity to your `TabLayout` like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    />
```

**Edit**:
In order to have the TabLayout below CollapsingToolbarLayout, simply put it into your ViewPager, like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/> 

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: That actually kinda work, but that's not what i'm looking for, i'd like for those tabs to be separate like [here](https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/android-tab-layout-app-bar-output-2.gif), now they look like [that](https://imgur.com/a/bZyXKvK)

Comment: In that case, the tablayout should be outside the appbar inside hte nested scrollview. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I thought that's what you're looking for. So the TabLayout shall be seperated from the AppBar?

Comment: In case it should be outside, so below the Toolbar, you can put the Toolbar into your ViewPager. I hope that's what you mean, otherwise just tell me

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that works, thanks. Now i need to fix the scrolling problem.

Comment: Great. Would you explain again what you want to have? So the AppBar only scrolls when you scroll the image, not the text, right? Shall the AppBar collapse, or scroll off screen?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, but Narayana Reddy's solution worked, i needed to change `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`. And his solution to catch everything in `LinearLayout` also worked, apparently it can be done in yours way or his, both work.

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear that!

Comment: This solution seems better than mine. Adding an additional LinearLayout like I did  increases the layout depth and reduces performance.

Comment: @NarayanaReddy No, to be more fair now, you were simply faster than me in the more difficult part of the problem. I would have solved it the same way, since it seems the most evident solution

Comment: You don't have to, was simply childish of me! I seriously apologize for that, hope I could fix it

Comment: I think I reversed all negatives I did, let me know if I am right on that! The votes on me were automatically reversed already. Hope you accept my apologies

Comment: Yeah, that was from StackOverflow support. Im partly to be blamed as well.

Comment: Well, I tempted it, so no reason to blame you

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/dash_bar"
    android:layout_height="192dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#b3ffffff"
            android:background="#00000000"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now to hide the image while scrolling the text, add this line to the View thats scrolling (i am assuming you just used textView and scrollbars there):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```